# SMTP without IMAP/POP communication

Tags: email, smtp

I would like to know if it's possible to use SMTP protocol to receive emails. In other words I'm not able to use IMAP or POP protocols because of some internal regulations of a company. If it's possible, could someone give me some example of how to do it? If not, is there a way to implement email receiver using other technologies?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  In fact, the SMTP protocol was designed explicitly for the purpose of sending and receiving emails.  The wikipedia page has some examples of email sent using the SMTP protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

If you are looking for source code to use as an example, I suggest trying GitHub: there are lots of SMTP projects in a variety of languages.

If you just need a working implementation, Microsoft Exchange is very popular.  There are also popular open source projects like Postfix, which you can download for free.